# Preventing user tampering through changing data values in PHP/AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, security

I have several forms where a user can make changes to events tied to their account but I'm not sure how to take care of security involving the user changing the value set in data-employeeID for example.

I initially set up a security check script that would look at an identifying piece of data coming in through ajax requests and before it goes on to actually use it. It would first do a series of mysql joins to work it's way back to the Users table and then do a final check to make sure the ID_NO of the users table can bej oined using the session stored userID.

I assume this would work and be secure. But the site is rather large, and often times 5 or 6 values are being passed though ajax calls. So on every public facing function I would need to repeat the process for each variable (Unless they can be tied together along the way; not always possible) before continuing on.

After googling around though I've only found results related to php/ajax processing errors, or security surrounding the user who is making the request.

If the user is legit though they can still make changes on the page, and keep all of the correct information except for changing something like the meeting ID to something else. If I only check the users CompanyID, or DepartmentID though my callback chain and skip meeting ID they will be able to get data inserted into the database that is not accurate, with a meeting possibly being manipulated because I didn't create a callback chain for every single variable being passed between ajax and PHP.

I feel there must be a better way and that this is a solved problem so I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction before I dive too deeply into making an over-complicated process. Thanks.

Requested Sample Code:

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "<?php echo base_url().'meetings/addstarttime/'?>",
    data: {
        validDaysID: this.dataset.validdaysid,
        departmentID: this.dataset.departmentID,
        companyID: this.dataset.companyID,
        employees: employeesArray,
        start: this.dataset.start
        },
    success: function(data){

        //update html to show updated values


$validDaysID = $_POST['validDaysID'];//unencoded
$securityArray[] = array("validDays", $validDaysID)//Check if access to this value is OK
$tieItBack[] = array("Buildings", "BuildingID");
$tieItBack[] = array("Location", "LocationID");
$tieItBack[] = array("Department", "DepartmentID");
$tieItBack[] = array("Companies", "CompanyID");
```

From there I make a query that selects the COUNT(*) of rows for the initially requested table, validDays, INNER JOINS the tables specified in the tieItBack chain and then finally checks if Companies.ID_NO == $this->session->userdata('CompanyID');

If there is a hit then they have access, if there is no rows then they do not.

For this example three of the variables can be knocked off in a single query but that is not always the case. Also this is using replaced table/col names cause I'm paranoid I guess but the structure is the same.

Comment: Server-side validation for performing a task is the only way.

Comment: Do you have example code you can provide? One good way is to utilize hash-values that can't be easily guessed and can be matched against, e.g. hash and salt the ID's on the user's end and compare against the hashed and salted value on the server. As MonkeyZeus mentioned, server-side validation is a must - you can't rely on client-side scripting to stop users from tampering data.

Comment: @SteveKnau I've added some code showing my process

Comment: There's no magic solution. Every page has to perform the appropriate validation checks in its queries.

Comment: Damn, at least it's good to know there isn't a better way and it simply has to be done.

Comment: Why are you trying to resolve the json, via the database back to the session? If your session security is not good enough, your security is not good enough. Store the reconcile value in the session and compare the JSON value directly with that.

Answer (score 0):

You have no reliable way of guaranteeing that [the client-side code is doing what you want it to do](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/03/client-authenticity-is-not-server-s-problem).

Your server-side software should distrust all input, regardless of whatever client-side validation you've already written. (Users might not even run JavaScript, for example.)

This isn't a problem that can magically be solved. It's just a reality about networked computers and software development.